# UIDocument Creation on iOS 11: reader is not permitted to access the URL

Tags: ios, ios11, uidocument, uti, document-based

Since iOS 11 I have encountered the following error **every time I am creating a new document** using `UIDocument` API:

> [ERROR] Could not get attribute values for item */var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/XXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX/Documents/myDoc-XXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX.myFile (n)*.
>
> Error: Error Domain=NSFileProviderInternalErrorDomain Code=1
> "The reader is not permitted to access the URL."
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The reader is not permitted to access the URL.}

Unlike similar questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45341934/document-creation-with-uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665946/having-trouble-getting-the-uidocumentbrowsercontroller-to-open-docs-in-a-documen), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47658935/xcode-9-2-uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller-failed-to-create-a-url-from-bookmark)) on SO on this, I am not using `UIDocumentBrowserViewController`. I am simply creating a UIDocument and call `save()` to the `Documents` directory myself. The [closest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47859376/uimanageddocument-savetourl-completionhandler-is-not-called-error-message-th) I found uses `UIManagedDocument`. However, in my case, **the file is still created and written successfully despite the error message.**

Here's the gist of my save routine:

```
@IBAction func createDoc(_ sender: Any) {
    let uuid = UUID().uuidString
    let doc = Document(baseName: "myDoc-\(uuid)")
    doc.save(to: doc.fileURL, for: .forCreating) { (completed) in
        if (completed) {
            doc.close(completionHandler: nil)
            self.verifyNumberOfFiles()
        }
    }
}
```

My `UIDocument` subclass is also almost blank for simplicity of this question:

```
class Document: UIDocument {    
    
    let fileExtension = "myFile"
    
    override init(fileURL url: URL) {
        super.init(fileURL: url)
    }

    /// Convenience method for `init(fileURL:)`
    convenience init(baseName: String) {
        self.init(fileURL: documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(baseName).appendingPathExtension(Document.fileExtension))
    }
    
    override func contents(forType typeName: String) throws -> Any {
        return NSData()
    }
    
    override func load(fromContents contents: Any, ofType typeName: String?) throws {
        
    }
    
}
```

I'm always writing to `Documents` folder, and my lookup routine can verify that my files are successfully created:

```
public var documentsDirectory: URL {
    return FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last!
}

func loadFileURLs(from dirURL: URL) -> [URL]? {
    return try? FileManager().contentsOfDirectory(at: dirURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
}
```

What I have discovered so far:

- The error appears even when I set up my UTI already. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45341934/document-creation-with-uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1587/_index.html).
- I can verify that my UTI works when I send a "myFile" to my device over AirDrop and it correctly triggers my app to open.
- **The error appears on iOS 11 only**. The same code doesn't reproduce the error on iOS 10, like in [the question above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47859376/uimanageddocument-savetourl-completionhandler-is-not-called-error-message-th).
- I tried adding `UISupportsDocumentBrowser` key although I'm not using the browser but it's not dissolve the error.

What is happening? Is this just a "noise" error message on iOS 11?

Here's  [my GitHub code online](https://github.com/pt2277/TestUIDocumentSave) if anyone is interested.

Comment: I came across this as well and would love to know about a proper fix for this. In the mean-time, my workaround is to first create the file and then use the usual way of opening an existing `UIDcument`: In `createDoc` first get the data for an empty document, call `try data.write(to: url)` and then initialise the `UIDocument` subclass and call `open` on it.

Comment: Also note that in my case the document was *not* created when the error popped up that you describe here, so it wasn't just a "noise" error.

Comment: @AdrianSchönig can you post some code in the answer section? Although it's not the "correct" answer, it'd add to the discussion. Thanks.

Comment: Same problem here. Error logged, but document is created.

Comment: I tested this in an iOS 11.3 simulator: the same error is still logged, but the document is created (as reported by @Mark above).

Answer (score 4):

A workaround for this is to create the file by saving its data to the disk, and then open it as you would with an existing file.

Your `createDoc(_:)` method would then like this:

```
@IBAction func createDoc(_ sender: Any) {
  let uuid = UUID().uuidString
  let baseName = "myDoc-\(uuid)"
  let url = documentsDirectory
      .appendingPathComponent(baseName)
      .appendingPathExtension(Document.fileExtension)

  do {
    let emptyFileData = Data()
    try emptyFileData.write(to: url)
    let document = Document(fileURL: url)
    document.open() { completed in
      guard completed else { 
        // handle error
        return 
      }
      doc.close(completionHandler: nil)
      self.verifyNumberOfFiles() 
    }
  } catch {
    // handle error
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 9.3 it is possible to specify a new item in info.plist:

Supports Document Browser (YES)

This enables access to the application's documents directory (for example, /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3C21358B-9E7F-4AA8-85A6-A8B901E028F5/Documents on a device). Apple Developer doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html).